# "all rooms" doesn't go to "all rooms"

Tags: bug, chat

While in a chat room, there are two buttons in the top right labeled "all rooms" and "site rooms". Clicking on "all rooms" opens chat.stackexchange.com but it's on whatever tab you were on last time you had that page open. This doesn't seem expected since there's a tab titled "all".

This also is different from "site rooms", which always takes you to the site rooms tab regardless of what tab you were on beforehand.

Is this intended?

Comment: Seems intentional.